# UIScrollview anchored from bottom when beginning

Tags: uiscrollview, anchor

I have a real tall uiimageview in a uiscrollview. The scrollview needs to begin at the bottom of the image view (fullscreen) and when you scroll down reveal the top. But it only lets me scroll up - which moves the bottom of the image off the screen. I know this is very easy but I am spacing here.

The uiscroll is in IB and in the viewdidload I do the following:

```
    uisv_background.scrollEnabled = YES;
[uisv_background setDelegate:self];
self.uisv_background.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.uisv_background.frame.size.width, 1024);
```

So, image should be 'anchored' to the bottom of the uiscrollview, and pulling down should reveal the top of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[self.uisv_background setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,256)];
```